# How do I change the background of my html screen to an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
    <div>
        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class = "container">
                <div class = "row">
                    
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 align-self-center">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                Register
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div>
                                    {{ form.hidden_tag()}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.fname, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.lname, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.email, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.phoneno, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.password, class="form-control")}}
                                    {{ render_field(form.confirm_password, class="form-control")}}
                                    
                                    {{ render_field(form.submit, class="btn btn-primary")}}
                                </div>
                                <p>Already have an account? <a href="{{ url_for('auth.login')}}">Login</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock app_content%}
```

This is my html code and what I want to do Is add an image as the background of the form so that the form is on the image (the image should cover the whole screen). How do I do that without an actual .css file?

Comment: You can inline the style with the `style` attribute or create a `<style>` section to place your css. Then just set the `background` property to set the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write CSS for the class of the div container of you form. Make this div have a background image:

> CSS

```
 .form-div {
  background-image: url("your_bg_image.jpg");
  width : 100 vw;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

> HTML

```
 <div class="form-div">
    <form>
    </form>
</div>
```

or

You may just make the image the background of the body of your html doc:

```
body  {
background-image: url("your_bg_image.jpg");
background-color: #cccccc;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Where is are your tag  < boby > in your example ? ?

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: url('yourImg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;  
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp

*-¸Teddy¸-*

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the background-image property to whichever div you want to have the background image. If you want it to be a background on the whole page maybe you should put it in the layout.html file you extend at the top.

```html
<div style="background-image: url('img_girl.jpg');">
```

[https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp][1]

Just a note that any css property doesn't have to be in a css file. You can add it to the top of your html file under a `<script>` tag.